# How can I "run" a Microstrategy report on Android?

Tags: android, microstrategy

In the begining of this week I tried a new software, the Microstrategy 9. I've created some documents, reports and prompts. Now I want to run this files in my cellphone. What do I need to do to pass these files from Microstrategy to my cellphone? Is there any emulator to run this reports on Windows?

Thanks.

Regards,
Gil.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Please use other resources, like Microstrategy support (http://www.microstrategy.com/services-support/) or http://android.stackexchange.com, for your non-programming Android questions.

Answer (score 3):

you have up to 10 licensed users for the MSTR free suite (that you are probably using).

you can use the MSTR PDF :MicroStrategy Mobile Design and Administration Guide
it have all the info you need.
or google for:configure microstrategy mobile server

basically you need to download the Microstrategy mobile app from the app store\google play
and then (assuming you installed the mobile component go to strat->all programs-->microstrategy tools-->mobile administrator)you configure the MSTR mobile server 
configure a device (Android phone in your case) and then you just send a url to your mail
you press the url from your mobile email and it will automatically define everything in your MSTR Mobile App to see your projects -it is all there

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take use of Microstrategy Mobile app . Download the and install app from android market .then you would require a licence for Microstrategy Mobile server . If you have that you have to configure your app to pint to your Mobile Server . MObile Server will point to the Intelligent server which will be responsible to process and run your report.

For configuring the app remotely you have to go to MobileAdmin Page . You will get options for Ipad , iphone and Android .
Select Android do all the required configuration and finally you will get a URL . Send this URL on your phone and open it in any browser. It will automatically configure your MSTR APP.
Then you can run your report directly from the app....but remember you can only view and interact with report on the , you cant modify anything. For modificaton use Desktop or WEB.

Thanks !

Please let me know if you need step by step procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible.

See below:

- [Microstrategy on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microstrategy.android.webapp)
- [More info](http://www.microstrategy.com/mobile/platform/)